# How do I get the current CPC bid for a keyword in Google AdWords API?

Tags: php, google-ads-api

How do I get the current bid for a keyword in my account? I tried

```
$adGroupCriterion->biddingStrategyConfiguration->bids[0]->bid->value * AdWordsConstants::MICROS_PER_DOLLAR;
```

But it gave me an error `'Trying to get property of non-object'`. When I add the keyword, I'm able to get the bid in the return value OK.

The bid doesn't appear to be selectable in a GET operation. I've searched all over the documentation for it.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/AdGroupCriterionService.BiddableAdGroupCriterion#biddingStrategyConfiguration

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/AdGroupCriterionService.Bids

> Although this field is returned in the response, it is ignored on input and cannot be selected.

I'm using this example to fetch the keywords:

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/v201502/BasicOperations/GetKeywords.php#L43

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it.

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201502/AdGroupCriterionService.CpcBid#bid

```
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'KeywordText', 'KeywordMatchType', 'AdGroupId', 'Status', 'CpcBid');
```

And I had the property and operator wrong:

```
$adGroupCriterion->biddingStrategyConfiguration->bids[0]->bid->microAmount / AdWordsConstants::MICROS_PER_DOLLAR;
```

Sorry to bother you.